# HBase client 1.0 get data failed

Tags: scala, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I met a problem about getting data by HBase v1.0 client API.

The followings are my HBase and custom Zookeeper settings:

**HMaster hosts**:

```
172.17.0.2     master
127.0.0.1      localhost
192.168.1.32   master2
```

**hbase-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
                <value>hdfs://master:9000/hbase</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
                <value>2181</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
                <value>/home/hduser/zookeeper/data</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
                <value>master</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.support.append</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

**zoo.cfg**:

```
dataDir=/home/hduser/zookeeper/data
clientPort=2181
server.1=master:2888:3888
```

After I run my client code to connect to zookeeper, it looks like this connection successful.

```
2015-04-09 08:51:37,901 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.1.30:56295
2015-04-09 08:51:37,906 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.1.30:56295
2015-04-09 08:51:37,939 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@617] - Established session 0x14c9d46501d000b with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /192.168.1.30:56295
2015-04-09 08:52:04,000 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@347] - Expiring session 0x14c9d46501d000a, timeout of 40000ms exceeded
2015-04-09 08:52:04,000 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@494] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x14c9d46501d000a
```

However, when I try to put a data into a table, there is nothing happened I observed in `zookeeper.out`

What's the possible problem under this circumstance?

The following code is what I try to connected to HBase by scala

**main.scala**:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val con = new HBaseUtils().getConnection
    try {

      val table = con.getTable(TableName.valueOf("TimeIndexTable"))
      val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("r2")).addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("post_info"), Bytes.toBytes("abc"), Bytes.toBytes("value"))
      table.put(put)
      println("Success")
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
    }
    finally {
      con.close()
    }

  }
}
```

**HBaseUtils.scala**:

```
class HBaseUtils {

  private val hbaseURL = "192.168.1.31"

  def getConnection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(setConf)

  def setConf = {
    val config = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",hbaseURL)
    config
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the data actually loaded? You could check it by running a hbase shell.

Comment: yes, I can put data via hbase shell

Comment: Could you make it clear what the exact problem is? Is it the scala program not loading data? or is that you cant see a update in zookeeper.out?

Comment: The problem is that I can put data by hbase shell but not by scala. And I didn't see any messages changed in zookeeper.out

Comment: In your scala program, your using the ip_address 192.168.1.31, while you master seems to be running with 172.17.0.2.Could this be the problem?

Comment: That's might be the problem. I will change the IP to 172.17.0.2 and export the scala program as jar running on server. Is it possible to manipulate hbase io on local machine instead of deploying on serever?